# Do two Firestore listeners that overlap bill for the same document update?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have two listeners both observing the same collection 'Tasks'.

- One query retrieves tasks that are incomplete (completed == false)
- The other query retrieves complete tasks within the last 24 hours (completed == true && completionDate > (Date - 24 hours))

Due to this logic the two listeners happen to overlap each other. If I update a task to complete. Both snapshot listeners will run. This is the same document however.

**Q:** Would I get charged TWICE for just updating one document? or will the listeners know that the same document has been updated once and will only be billed once?

```
class TaskData: ObservableObject {
    @Published var tasks: [Task] = []
    @Published var incompleteTasks: [Task] = []
    @Published var completedTasks: [Task] = []
    
    private var db = Firestore.firestore()
    private var incompleteTaskslistenerRegistration: ListenerRegistration?
    private var completedTasksListenerRegistration: ListenerRegistration?
    
    init() {
        subscribe()
        
        Publishers
            .CombineLatest($completedTasks, $incompleteTasks)
            .dropFirst()
            .map { $0 + $1 }
            .assign(to: &$tasks)
    }
    
    deinit {
        unsubscribe()
    }
    
    func subscribe() {
        guard let userId = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
                
        if incompleteTaskslistenerRegistration != nil || completedTasksListenerRegistration != nil {
            unsubscribe()
        }
        
        let completedTasksQuery = db.collection("tasks")
            .whereField("userId", isEqualTo: userId)
            .whereField("completed", isEqualTo: true)
            .whereField("completedDate", isGreaterThan: Date().advanced(by: -86400))
        
        completedTasksListenerRegistration = completedTasksQuery.addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, error in
            guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
                print("No documents in 'tasks' collection")
                return
            }
            self.completedTasks = documents.compactMap { queryDocumentSnapshot in
                try? queryDocumentSnapshot.data(as: Task.self)
            }
        }
        
        let incompleteTasksQuery = db.collection("tasks")
            .whereField("userId", isEqualTo: userId)
            .whereField("completed", isEqualTo: false)
        
        incompleteTaskslistenerRegistration = incompleteTasksQuery.addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, error in
            guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
                print("No documents in 'tasks' collection")
                return
            }
            self.incompleteTasks = documents.compactMap { queryDocumentSnapshot in
                try? queryDocumentSnapshot.data(as: Task.self)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func unsubscribe() {
        if incompleteTaskslistenerRegistration != nil {
            incompleteTaskslistenerRegistration?.remove()
            incompleteTaskslistenerRegistration = nil
        }
        if completedTasksListenerRegistration != nil {
            completedTasksListenerRegistration?.remove()
            completedTasksListenerRegistration = nil
        }
    }
}
```

## Edit 1

I just want to clarify that the reason I have the query for retrieving completed tasks for the past 24 hours is so that users are able to uncheck or make changes in that period. It will then be no longer fetched. I don’t want add a listener that fetches all the tasks ever made as that would start costing a lot and I don’t want to implement pagination as I lose that real-time updating and pagination for listeners is rather strenuous.

Comment: Why two listeners? When you can do it with one. 
There is logical error and due to two listeners it will read more data more charges

Comment: The completedDate field is optional. It can be nil if it is incomplete. My isGreaterThan query will only fetch the completed tasks then.

Comment: but you can populate completed and incomplete in just one array tasks and then filter both from that array with just one listener ?

Comment: I am having a hard time understanding your solution. Are you saying that I query for all tasks ever made by a particular user. Then with application code filter out the tasks that are not completed and completed within the last 24 hours?

Comment: yes this is the right way to achieve it

Comment: This means hypothetically that if a user has 100 tasks completed last year and 1 incomplete task this year. 101 documents will be fetched. Why bother displaying completed tasks last year, my application does not need that information - it is irrelevant as it is completed. I want the completed tasks in the last 24 hours to enable the user the ability to uncheck it if they made a mistake or something changes with the task

Comment: guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents after this line remove the other listener

Answer (score 0):

[Cloud Firestore charges you for the number of documents you read, write and delete](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing#listens), so you are charged for a read each time a document in the result is updated.

Since you have two active listeners that run the same document, the first listener will need to get or check the data from the server (document) while the second listener can read it from cache.